# How to determine when NSURLSessionTask's request begins?

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsurlsession, nsurlsessiontask

I use `NSURLSessionTask`s and I'm trying to monitor how long some of my HTTP Requests take, what delegate method (or something else) can I monitor for when the `NSURLSessionTask` actually makes the initial request?  If this were a `NSURLConnection` inside an `NSOperation` I'd just start a timer when I start the request but I don't have control over when tasks start.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please check **NSURLSessionTaskDelegate**. It has following delegate callbacks:

```
URLSession:task:didCompleteWithError:
URLSession:task:didReceiveChallenge:completionHandler:
URLSession:task:didSendBodyData:totalBytesSent:totalBytesExpectedToSend:
URLSession:task:needNewBodyStream:
URLSession:task:willPerformHTTPRedirection:newRequest:completionHandler:
```

To calculate time interval.

**Option 01 [Approximate]:**

You should start a timer just after the call to resume method and and calculate when the delegate callback didCompleteWithError is invoked.

```
self.dataTask = [self.session dataTaskWithRequest:theRequest];
[self.dataTask resume];

NSTimeInterval totalCountdownInterval;
NSDate* startDate = [NSDate date];
NSTimer* timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0 target:self selector:@selector(checkCountdown:) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
```

**Option 02 [If accuracy is desired]:**

NSURLSessionTask’s properties are all KVO-compliant.

```
[self.dataTask addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"someKeyPath" options:NSKeyValueObservingOptionOld context:nil];
[self.dataTask resume];

- (void)observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath ofObject:(id)object change:(NSDictionary *)change context:(void *)context{
  // do some calculation after checking state

   /* 
NSURLSessionTaskStateRunning = 0,                     
    NSURLSessionTaskStateSuspended = 1,
    NSURLSessionTaskStateCanceling = 2,                   
    NSURLSessionTaskStateCompleted = 3, */
}
```

Comment: Those are all great ways to determine when its done/redirecting/etc but none of them indicate when the request is initially made.

Comment: Thats closer but that would assume that when you call `resume` the request is made immediately which isn't always the case, `resume` just indicates that the task should be allowed to run.

Comment: If accuracy is desired. You can use option02: I added sample code.

Comment: I also arrived at the KVO option, it works perfectly, I came back here to add my own answer but you beat me to it :)

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old question but for those searching the delegate method
func urlSession(_ session: URLSession, task: URLSessionTask, didFinishCollecting metrics: URLSessionTaskMetrics)
on URLSessionTaskDelegate should be able to provide plenty of info about the request including how long it took.

Answer (score 0):

Two options:

1. If you want, you could implement the delegate based rendition of `NSURLSession` and then capture the elapsed time between `didReceiveResponse` and `didCompleteWithError`. This admittedly doesn't capture the latency involved in receiving the response, but if you're looking for a simple measure that factors out the time waiting for an available connection, that's one approach.
2. The other approach is to wrap the `NSURLSessionTask` objects in a `NSOperation` subclass, just like you did with `NSURLConnection`. This is trivial in the case where you are using the completion block rendition of the `NSURLSessionTask` factory methods. It's a little more cumbersome when using the delegate based approach (because, infuriatingly, `NSURLSession` doesn't allow us to specify delegate objects for the individual tasks (even though they let us associate completion blocks for them), but rather all of the task-specific delegate methods are called at the session object level).

   Anyway, when you wrap it in a `NSOperation` subclass, you can capture your complete elapsed time quite easily.

Comment: Yea #1 won't work because I'm interested in the latency, #2 looks attractive but I think you're right that it'll be cumbersome, I'm trying KVO on the `NSURLSessionTaskState` property and so far its looking like a good solution.