# is it possible to "Pause" and "Resume" AVAssetDownloadTask?

Tags: ios, objective-c, avurlasset, avassetdownloadtask

so far i found only two options for downloading video either "Resume" or "cancel"/"Suspend". is there any possible way to pause downloading video in middle and resume the download from where it stopped. I am using below code to download and store the video.

```
  // Create new background session configuration.
    NSURLSessionConfiguration *urlSessionConfiguration = [NSURLSessionConfiguration backgroundSessionConfigurationWithIdentifier:@"assetDowloadConfigIdentifier"];
    AVAssetDownloadURLSession *avAssetDownloadSession = [AVAssetDownloadURLSession sessionWithConfiguration:urlSessionConfiguration assetDownloadDelegate:self delegateQueue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue]];

    NSURL *assetURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://a4i6y2k6.stackpathcdn.com/vistvorigin/smil:4b0d690b7b3bc8ac5da2049f50c80794c762423e.smil/playlist.m3u8"];

    AVURLAsset *hlsAsset = [AVURLAsset assetWithURL:assetURL];

   if (@available(iOS 10.0, *)) {

        AVAssetDownloadTask *avAssetDownloadTask = [avAssetDownloadSession assetDownloadTaskWithURLAsset:hlsAsset assetTitle:@"downloadedMedia" assetArtworkData:nil options:nil];

        if([command isEqualToString:@"resume"]){
            // Start task and begin download
            [avAssetDownloadTask resume];
        }else{
            [avAssetDownloadTask cancel];
        }

    } else {
        // Fallback on earlier versions
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in here you can use the state of [`suspend`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsurlsessiontask/1411565-suspend)

> A task, while suspended, produces no network traffic and is not subject to timeouts. A download task can continue transferring data at a later time. All other tasks must start over when resumed.

if you want to find your current task state use [`state`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsurlsessiontask/1409888-state?language=objc)  property, it will return the current state , the states are following

```
 /* 
NSURLSessionTaskStateRunning = 0,                     
NSURLSessionTaskStateSuspended = 1,
NSURLSessionTaskStateCanceling = 2,                   
NSURLSessionTaskStateCompleted = 3,
```

for e.g you can use as like

```
 NSURL *assetURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://a4i6y2k6.stackpathcdn.com/vistvorigin/smil:4b0d690b7b3bc8ac5da2049f50c80794c762423e.smil/playlist.m3u8"];

AVURLAsset *hlsAsset = [AVURLAsset assetWithURL:assetURL];

if (@available(iOS 10.0, *)) {

    AVAssetDownloadTask *avAssetDownloadTask = [avAssetDownloadSession assetDownloadTaskWithURLAsset:hlsAsset assetTitle:@"downloadedMedia" assetArtworkData:nil options:nil];
    if(avAssetDownloadTask.state ==  1){
        // Start task and begin download
        [avAssetDownloadTask resume];
    }else{
        [avAssetDownloadTask cancel];
    }


} else {
    // Fallback on earlier versions
}
```

**Option 2**

if you want to perform in KVO pattern , please see this [SO past answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26145915/how-to-determine-when-nsurlsessiontasks-request-begins)